# After clicking on button popup not showing in angulr6 project

Tags: angular6

I am  doing project in angular6. I have created registration form, and I have called two functions at a time, one function for form submit, and other for open popup,as shown in the code. After clicking on submit button, the form values need to be show in popup, with final submit button, but here after clicking on submit button form getting submit but popup not getting open. I am not getting where I have done mistake. Any help please

registration.html

In this file I have called two functions at a time.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">Header
</nav>
<div class="container">
   <form [formGroup]="addForm" (ngSubmit)=[onSubmit(addForm.value),openModal()]> 

    <h2 class="text-center mt-3">Registration Form</h2>
    <div class="card-header mt-3 mb-3">Student Registration</div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="usn"><strong>USN</strong></label>
          <input type="usn" formControlName="usn" placeholder="usn" name="usn" class="form-control" id="usn">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="firstName"><strong>First Name</strong></label>
          <input type="firstName" formControlName="firstName" placeholder="FirstName" name="firstName" class="form-control" id="firstName" ngModel>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-success mx-auto d-block" >Submit</button>
</div>
```

registration.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from "@angular/forms";
    import {Router} from "@angular/router";
    import {Inject} from '@angular/core';
    import {MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material';
    import { DisplayDataComponent } from '../display-data/display-data.component';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-student-parent-registration',
      templateUrl: './student-parent-registration.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./student-parent-registration.component.css']
    })
    export class StudentParentRegistrationComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private router: Router, public dialog: MatDialog) { }

    addForm: FormGroup;

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log("ngOnInit called")
          this.addForm = this.formBuilder.group({
          usn:[''],
          firstName:['']
        });
      }

     onSubmit(data) {
        console.log(data);`
        openModal(){
   console.log("calling")
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DisplayDataComponent, {
      width: '250px',
          });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed');
    });
  }

}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { StudentParentRegistrationComponent } from './student-parent-registration/student-parent-registration.component';
import { BsDatepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';
import { DisplayComponent } from './display/display.component';
import { DisplayDataComponent } from './display-data/display-data.component';
import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    StudentParentRegistrationComponent,
    DisplayComponent,

    DisplayDataComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    BsDatepickerModule.forRoot()
  ],

  entryComponents: [
  DisplayDataComponent
  ],

  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

After clicking on button not getting popup

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are not closing your form tag

Comment: Yeah. I have closed form tag. But still not working.

Comment: perhaps you are missing the bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [DisplayDataComponent] in app.module, if not, can you share the messages (if any) shown in developer tools?

Comment: Okay. I have attached screenshot regarding messages which are showing in developer tool. Please find  this link. https://imgur.com/1yTm1Yh

Comment: Actually I didn't add pre-built theme in style.css. And now I have included theme in style.css. Now I am getting popup.